# How to delete disabled options in a drop-down HTML select list in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to iterate through a  element, removing all disabled elements from the list so that the users are presented only with the items relevant to them. All this is happening in Drupal 7 with the select list being populated from a list of Taxonomy terms. I notice two problems, but first this is my javascript file in a custom theme:

```
(function($) 
{
    Drupal.behaviors.mytheme = 
    {
        attach: function(context, settings) 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("edit-field-diplomatic-mission-und");

            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) //Force loop
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                {
                    if (x.options[i].disabled == true)
                    {
                        x.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

1. The loop does not go through the entire list but breaks at random, around the 21st or 25th option. Thet is why I have a force loop within the code
2. The disabled elements don't get deleted at all in Drupal

Just as a note, on its own stand-alone format, the same code works OK deleting the elements through the entire list, without the loop:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("edit-field-diplomatic-mission-und");

            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                {
                    if (x.options[i].disabled == true)
                    {
                        x.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: If using Jquery: `$('select option:disabled').remove()`

Comment: I am not sure if you need to do this at all. Why do u need to del or remove disabled options ?  What I understand is u have a list which is shown to a user and u don't want some values to be shown. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are removing options which affects `options` collection length (which is live NodeList). You can loop backwards. This is correct code to remove all disabled options:

```
var x = document.getElementById("edit-field-diplomatic-mission-und");

for (var i = x.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (x.options[i].disabled) {
        x.remove(i);
    }
}
```

or

```
var i = x.options.length;
while (i--) {
    if (x.options[i].disabled) {
        x.remove(i);
    }
}
```

In general `x.length` makes no sense because `x` is a single DOMElement it's not a collection.

Finally since you are using jQuery you should definitely go with it:

```
$('#edit-field-diplomatic-mission-und option:disabled').remove();
```

Comment: `$('#edit-field-diplomatic-mission-und option:disabled').remove();` sounds most decent but it is not working. Neither do the other loops.

Comment: `for (var i = x.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` loops through the entire options list OK. And, yes, am running the script when DOM is ready.

Comment: I have even tried `x.options[i].getAttribute("disabled")` but that returns null

Comment: Post a problematic demo. Include HTML you are dealing with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63546/discussion-between-benda-and-dfsq).